# Rgegexpression - select according to occurrences

Tags: regex, numbers

I have 
[1] "43300" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "44200" "32122" "22222" "22222" "55000" "22222" "55000" "22222" "33220" "22222" 
[17] "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "32221" "22222" "55000" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "22222" "33220" "33310"

How do I select the ones (inside "") with

a) no occurrence of 0 
b) exactly 1 occurrence of 0 
c) exactly 2 occurrences of 0 
d) exactly 3 occurrences of 0 etc.

for a) ([1-5^0]+) didn't work

Comment: could u elaborate what you want.. It is not clear..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
"((?:[1-5]*0){N}[1-5]*)"
```

For example:

- `"((?:[1-5]*0){3}[1-5]*)"` - 3 zeros
- `"((?:[1-5]*0){2}[1-5]*)"` - 2 zeros
- `"((?:[1-5]*0){1}[1-5]*)"` - 1 zeros, same as `"([1-5]*0[1-5]*)"`
- `"((?:[1-5]*0){0}[1-5]*)"` - 0 zeros, same as `"([1-5]*)"`

You can also remove the quotes and capturing group, and use word boundaries instead:

```
\b(?:[1-5]*0){N}[1-5]*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no leading zeros:

a) `[1-9]+`

b) `[1-9]+0[1-9]*`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

if count of digit in string = 5

a) `[^0]{5}`

b) `[^0]{4}`

c) `[^0]{3}`

d) `[^0]{2}`